# TensorFlow: Reshaping embedding vectors after lookup?

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding

I'm using TensorFlow for the first time, and am having trouble understanding the `embedding_lookup` function. I have a series of indices that represent a single feature vector, let's say `[0,3,2,5]`. I want to replace those indices with their corresponding embeddings, so I put the embeddings and the index vector through `embedding_lookup`. It then returns a 4 X n tensor, where n is the length of each embedding. My thought, and perhaps I'm misunderstanding things, is that I instead want this to be a single row vector of length 4*n, which I should be able to accomplish by reshaping.

And if, instead of sending `embedding_lookup` a single instance's feature indices, I want to send it the indices for every instance in the data set, assuming each list was of length 4, it would return a m X 4 X n tensor (where m is the size of the set), which I would want to reshape to m X n*4. Assuming I'm not already way off track here, I'm doing this with the following code:

```
... # Stuff

word_embeddings = tf.Variable(self.word_embeddings, name="embeddings")

feature_ids = tf.placeholder(
    tf.int32, shape=(None, input_size), name="feature_ids")
X = tf.reshape(
    tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embeddings, feature_ids), [len(features),-1], name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name='y')

with tf.name_scope("nn"):
    hidden1 = fully_connected(X, hidden_size1, scope="hidden1")
    hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1, hidden_size2, scope="hidden2")
    output = fully_connected(hidden2, output_size, activation_fn=None, scope="output")

... # More stuff
```

But what I'm getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 84, in test
    hidden1 = fully_connected(X, hidden_size1, scope="hidden1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1469, in fully_connected
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 492, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 434, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 109, in build
    raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to expand the shape from (4, n) to (m, 4, n)

and use [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) to change the shape from (m, 4, n) to (m, n, 4).

In this case, the perm parameter of the transpose func would be [0, 2, 1]

(Don't use tf.reshape when transpose!!!)